# Can't find SQL Server Network Configuration Protocols

Tags: sql-server-2008

After installing SQL Server 2008 32 bit, I tried to configure it to allow remote access. So I opened the SQL Server Configuration Manager to set up the protocols to enabled. I did not find any protocol under the SQL Server Network Configuration... I have been using windows xp

Anyone encountered this before ?